# Is the following object a tensor?

Tags: tensors

Consider the following mathematical object constructed out of tensors:

$$\mathbf{Re} = \frac{\rho \vec{v} \cdot\nabla \vec{v}}{\mu \nabla \cdot \nabla \vec{v}}$$

$\rho$ and $\mu$ are $(0,0)$ tensors and $\vec{v}$ is a $(1,0)$ tensor.

**Is this object a tensor, i.e. does it transform like a tensor?**

For clarity, if I fixed an orthonormal coordinate system to ignore raising/lowering indexes, my expression for the components of $\mathbf{Re}$ would be the following in index notation, following the Einstein summation convention:

$$Re_{ij} = \frac{\rho v_k \frac{\partial v_k}{\partial x_i}}{\mu \frac{\partial^2 v_j}{\partial x_l \partial x_l}}$$

Comment: If you work with usual notation, this is just a number.

Comment: Are you sure the numerator isn't $\sum_k v_k\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_k}$ and the denominator isn't $\sum_k\frac{\partial^2 v_i}{\partial x_k^2}$?

Comment: @amsmath The objects on the numerator and denominator both have, in 3-D, three components; the overall object represents the division of each of the components on the numerator by each of the components on the denominator, resulting in 9 distinct components. It has to be either a second-order tensor or a symbol. (Note the indexed expression at the bottom of the question.)

Comment: @TedShifrin You're right about the second one, thanks! Fixing now. My expression for the first term isn't equivalent to yours, I think; the expression you wrote is $\nabla \vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}$, which is in the opposite order.